# Copy on write is an interesting idea used on server systems. Does it make any sense on a smartphone?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, operating-system, paging

The data pages that are actually modified need to be copied. This approach, called copy on write, improves performance by reducing copying.

According to me it is unnecessary as every process has its own data. (not sure)
A third process working with that data is really not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Data can differ. Code, stack/heap and so on.
If you open notepad twice, it is 2 different processes yet they share `code` pages in memory where they read instructions.

Same goes for phones. You could possibly be able to open the same application twice I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider that that there is a text file on your mobile phone and you have two applications to edit text. If you open this text file simultaneously within the two applications and the two applications are having different copies of the same text file, you are basically having redundant data. So I don't think copy-on-write can be ruled out as unnecessary. HTH.